# trouble connecting Flask-SocketIO with Node socket.io-client or ngx-socket-io

Tags: python, angular, ionic-framework, flask, socket.io

currently I'm developing a realtime chat app with Ionic and Flask_SocketIO

I do need Flask as Backend since I'm handling authentication with Flask_login.
The issue appears to be on the nodejs-angular-ionic side of my application. It is possible for the app to connect and authenticate properly but as soon as I emit a message from my IonicClient to other clients (e.g. from web) they seem to stop receiving but I'm still able to emit messages from those clients. 
The Server actually does list them as connected. So there might be a request conflict.

If I just use clients from the web my chat works perfectly, this makes me believe that it has something to do with our nodejs-angular-ionic-app

Neither the FlaskBackend nor the WebClients nor the IonicClients show error messages.

**FLASK_BACKEND**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_socketio import emit, join_room, leave_room, SocketIO, send, disconnect
import functools
from flask_login import current_user, LoginManager
from flask import g
from datetime import datetime
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
from flask_socketio import ConnectionRefusedError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False, cors_allowed_origins='*') #http://127.0.0.1:5000
login = LoginManager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

room = None

def confirm_token(token, expiration=86400):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        id = serializer.loads(
            token,
            salt=app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'],
            max_age=expiration
        )
    except:
        return False
    return id


from models import UserModel, MessageModel

@login.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):
    # first, try to login using the api_key url arg
    id = request.args.get('id')
    if id:
        id = confirm_token(id)
        if id:
            g.login_via_header = True
            user = UserModel.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
            db.session.close_all()
            if user:
                return user
        else:
            return None
    else:
        print("No id found")
        return None

def authenticated_only(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or current_user.is_anonymous:
            print("current_user is anonymous")
            disconnect()
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped



@socketio.on('joined')
@authenticated_only
def joined(message):
    """Sent by clients when they enter a room.
    A status message is broadcast to all people in the room."""
    global room
    room = message['room']
    join_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': str(current_user.first) + ' is now Online.'}, room=room, skip_sid=True)
    print(current_user.first, "joined room no.", room)


@socketio.on('text')
@authenticated_only
def text(message):
    """Sent by a client when the user entered a new message.
    The message is sent to all people in the room."""
    global room
    msg = MessageModel(
        owner = current_user,
        room = room,
        message = str(message['msg']),
        timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    )
    try:
        msg.save_to_db()
        emit('message', {'msg': message['msg'],
            'u_id': current_user.id,
            'u_pp': current_user.profile_picture,
            'u_name': current_user.first }, room=room, skip_sid=True)
        print(current_user.first + ": " + str(message['msg']))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print("Bye", current_user.first)
    global room
    leave_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': str(current_user.first) + ' is now Offline.'}, room=room, skip_sid=True)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=3001)
```

**Ionic**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const SOCKET_URL = 'http://192.168.0.125:3001?id='

@Component({
  selector: 'app-job-detail',
  templateUrl: './job-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-detail.page.scss'],
})


export class JobDetailPage implements OnInit {
  private id: string;
  private token: string = "MQ.XoxlTg.Pjd8WcW_e2ywu5YeabBwToz53nM";

  messages = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private socket: Socket,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.socket.ioSocket.io.opts.query = {cookie: false, transports: ['websocket']};
    this.socket.ioSocket.io.uri = SOCKET_URL + this.token; //new uri
    this.socket.connect(); //manually connection

    this.socket.fromEvent('connect').subscribe( () => {
      this.socket.emit('joined', {room: this.id});
    });

    this.socket.fromEvent('disconnect').subscribe(() => {
      console.log("You disconnected from our chat servers")
    })



    //this.socket.fromEvent('status').subscribe(data => {
    //  console.log(data)
    //});
  }


  sendMessage(msg) {
    this.socket.emit('text', {
      msg: msg
    });
  }
```

**WEB**:

```
socket = io("http://192.168.0.125:3001?id={{chattoken}}", { transports: ['websocket'] });
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('joined', {room: room_id});
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log("You disconnected from our Chat servers")
            });
            socket.on('status', function(data) {
                console.log("Received A StatusUpdate")
                $('#chat').html($('#chat').html() + '<div style="text-align: center">' + data.msg + '</div><br>');
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                console.log("Received A Message")
                if (data.u_id == user_id) {
                    $('#chat').html($('#chat').html() + outgoing_msg + data.msg + outgoing_msg_end);
                } else {
                    var d = new Date();
                    var h = addZero(d.getHours());
                    var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
                    if (data.u_pp == "missing") {
                        $('#chat').html($('#chat').html() + incoming_msg + "<div class=\"incoming_msg_img\"> <img src=\"{{ url_for('static', filename='images/missing.png') }}\"> </div>" + incoming_msg_middle + data.msg + incoming_msg_end + data.u_name +
                            " today, " + h + ":" + m + incoming_msg_end_1);
                    } else {
                        $('#chat').html($('#chat').html() + incoming_msg + "<div class=\"incoming_msg_img\" style=\"background-image: url('" + data.u_pp + "'); background-size:cover; border-radius: 4rem;\"> </div>" + incoming_msg_middle + data.msg +
                            incoming_msg_end + data.u_name + " today, " + h + ":" + m + incoming_msg_end_1);
                    }
                }

                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
```

After further investigation I've found those Issues:
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/47
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/253#issuecomment-233241257

But since I also tried out ngx-socket-io and the issues being from 2016 I don't think they are relevant.

Thanks in advance,

flixoflax